# Can a hunter attack diagonally?

Tags: specter-ops

The rules state that line of sight for a hunter is down the row and column it is on. However, if an agent has been spotted by one hunter, can another hunter attack diagonally since the position of the agent is known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/specter-ops-shadow-of-babel/rules.pdf) (page 5 bottom right):

> After a hunter moves, if the agent is visible to that hunter, that hunter
>   may attack the agent.

So no, a hunter has to see its own target, you can't use another hunter's line of sight for that.